# MicroStream used as a search server

Tags: java, eclipse, microstream

I am evaluating MicroStream. I have understood it is a storage engine for storing, loading and updating object graphs partially. From MicroStream's perspective my object-graph in the memory is my in-memory database. For queries I can use Java streams. If this is correct, I should be able to use lucene to create a search server like elastic search very easily, right?

The advantage of a MicroStream search server would be that it works with real Java objects instead of key-value, JSON or something like that. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for this search. Java stream search are very fast. I have tested it and for almost 140 000 objects takes full search 30 ms and filter 9655 objects.